# What's the acceptable short name for the place where cars are normally repaired?

Tags: word-request

What's the most common name for the place where cars can be repaired? 
Looking at the parallel article on English [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automobile_repair_shop) shows me that this place called "**An automobile repair shop**" but I believe that nobody is really says this very long name because it isn't comfortable. The article denotes that it is also known **regionally** as a **garage** or a **workshop**. So I understand that it depends on regions.

What's the most acceptable short name for this place? (In the UK and in the USA as well)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Generally, in the US, I would say garage would be most common. You'll often just refer to the person as well (in other words, "the car is at the mechanic's"). Also, if your preferred car service location is the service department of the local car dealer, many people just say "I took the car to the dealer".

Comment: Thank you for the answer (+1^). But what does it mean "car mechanic's"? the s' in the end stands for what?

Comment: "mechanic's shop", you'll often hear people drop the "shop" in speech.

Comment: b.t.w. as much as I understand, the word *garage* has a lot of meaning regards the car, from the place where one parks the car through the place where is repaired to the place where it gets fuel (gas station). From here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/garage

Comment: I would also add that "mechanic" without the possessive is fine too, at least in Canada. And in Springfield you can call it a ["car hole"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=JhbJnlIvfyc).

Comment: The word 'garage' is very common in Britain. The precise meaning is supplied by context - I arrived home and put my car is in the garage (=the small building for keeping the car in, next to or attached to the house); I am low on fuel; I'll stop at the next garage (=a petrol/gas station); my car is in the garage having a new silencer fitted (=a car repair place).

Comment: @Perplexed folks -  "the s' in the end stands for what?" We get our hair cut at the barber's, our medicine at the doctor's, our vegetables at the grocer's, our cat treated at the vet's. The possessive in each of these relates to something which is in omitted in everyday speech, because everybody knows what it is.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Thank you, I learnt something new today. I really did not that people say "I am at the doctor's" etc. That's good to know.

Answer (score 1):

It's [very common](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/is-your-car-in-the-shop-shop-automobile-repair-shop.3261264/) in the US to say that "the car is in the **shop**".